# How to assert that a string can be used as an array index w/o converting/asserting it to/as a number?

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-assertion, array-indexing

I have a string value, which I intend to use as an index of an array. I'm sure of this value and want to assert that it's a valid 'index value', w/o converting it to a number at runtime or asserting it's a number (b/c it's not a number).

So I have:

```
const inputEl = window.document.getElementById('foo') as HTMLInputElement;
//it's indeed a string, I'm sure of it and have no squirm because of it
const v = inputEl.value as string;
const a = ['foo',];
const result = a[v];

console.log(result);
```

Currently `tsc` throws

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number' (tsserver 7015)
```

I'd rather not do something like:

```
//just because it's not a number
const v = inputEl.value as unknown as number;
```

Is there a better way to do it? Thank you.

Comment: A string can't be used as an array index. Array indexes are always numbers. If you want to use a string as key, you should use an object.

Comment: @jabaa does it mean that I must convert it to a number at runtime, like `const num = Number(v);`

Comment: TypeScript expects numbers as keys. JavaScript allows strings and implicitly converts them. I would explicitly convert the strings, avoid the implicit conversion and solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just *don't* use the input `.value` string. Use its `.valueAsNumber`.